# Module does not show up in blocks (6.x)

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a module that I've activated, but it does not show up in the disabled blocks list.

The module is named "My Module."
Inside the my_module folder I have the following files:

- my_module.module
- my_module.info

#### my_module.info

```
name = My Module
description = My module description.
core = 6.x
package = My Modules
```

#### my_module.module

```
<?php
function hook_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()){
  switch ($op) {
    case 'list':
      $block = array();
      //List out all blocks you want to create here
      $block[0]["info"] = t('Display info'); 
      break;    
    case 'view':    
      switch ($delta) {
        case 0:
          global $user;
          $block['subject'] = "ADMIN Header of the block";

          if (in_array('Site admin', array_values($user->roles) || $user->uid == 1)) {
            $block['content'] = "input form";
            $block['subject'] = "Header of the block";
          }     
          break;
      }
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `function hook_block` to `function my_module_block`, and add `return $block;` to the end of the 'list' and  'view' cases.

Comment: Thank you! Also had to add `return $block;` to the list case for it to show up.